# CSS after with many lang tag

Tags: html, css

How to better write this code with three translations? I want to use only one class with three translations instead of three class, my code:

```
.test > li.nav-item:lang(en):nth-child(1):after {
    content: "BNM";
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.test > li.nav-item:lang(fr):nth-child(1):after {
    content: "XYZ";
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.test > li.nav-item:lang(pl):nth-child(1):after {
    content: "YUI";
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

i want something like this:

```
.test > li.nav-item:nth-child(1) 
      &:lang(en):after {}
      &:lang(fr):after {}
      &:lang(pl):after {}
```

or something like this

Comment: you can do that with scss, sass

Comment: can you show example?

Comment: but I would like to use css :(

Comment: okay :), don't know how to do that in css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a preprocessor you can reduce the code using a CSS variable, e.g.

```css
:lang(en) { --label: "BNM"; }
:lang(fr) { --label: "XYZ"; }
:lang(pl) { --label: "YUI"; }


li.nav-item:nth-child(1)::after {
  margin-left: 10px;
  content: var(--label);
}
```

```html
<ul class="test" lang="pl">
   <li class="nav-item">1</li>
   <li class="nav-item">2</li>
   <li class="nav-item">3</li>
</ul>
```

If no `lang` attribute is defined then the `--label` variable will be undefined and will not be written in the `::after` pseudoelement.

Comment: I need to use `lang='pl'` in html `li`?

Comment: that is what I assume your css code should do without seeing your markup, but you can place it somewhere else (see my edit). You could also place it in the `<html>` element